# Is it possible to find these numbers without converting them into cubic equation?

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

> $abc = k$
>
> $ab + bc + ac = l$
>
> $a+b+c = m$
>
> ($k$, $l$ and $m$ are known. $a\geq b\geq c$, $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$)

Is it possible to solve this equation system for $a$, $b$ and $c$ by **only** manipulating the equations (squaring, cubing, adding, subtracting, cube rooting...)?

I'm sure that there's a way, here's a [quote](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbelsImpossibilityTheorem.html):

> In general, polynomial equations higher than fourth degree are incapable of algebraic solution in terms of a finite number of additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions, and root extractions. This was also shown by Ruffini in 1813 (Wells 1986, p. 59).

Comment: To solve *which* equation system? You mean, $abc=n$,$a+b+c=m$ and $a+b+c=k$ over the integers?

Comment: @MCCCS: Are there any restrictions on $a,b,c$ other than $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \ge b \ge c$, and the given equations?

Comment: @quasi a, b, c are complex.

Comment: For complex $a,b,c$ inequalities $a\ge b\ge c$ do not make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly not.

If that was possible, we would have an alternative method of solving a cubic equation.

In a way, solving a cubic equation without solving a cubic equation :)

---

And as it seems that the values are real (you can order them), you cannot do without the trigonometric approach, this is a "casus irreductibilis".

Comment: As the question was updated by the OP, the last paragraph is now irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I don't see how to avoid a cubic for complex solutions. For example, solve the system
\begin{align*}
abc & = 1,\\
ab+bc+ca & = 2,\\
a+b+c & = 3.
\end{align*}
The solutions are given by the roots of the cubic 
$$
c^3-3c^2+2c-1=0,
$$
and quadratic equations for $a$ and $b$. Whatever we do otherwise, must involve these roots of the cubic.

Comment: @MCCCS: Said differently: If there was another method for solving such systems of equations, that would yield another method for solving cubic equations.